# List javascript tasks in Visual Studio Task list

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, todo, tasklist

Is there a way to configure Visual Studio 2008 to display TODO comments in .js files or script-tags in the task list?
Now only todo comments from the C# code is displayed.

Answer (score 10):

Another option is to just use Resharper's To-do Explorer window, which you probably already have and if not, should have.  You can dock it right with the other windows.  It parses all the files (cs, js, css, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

http://forums.asp.net/t/414634.aspx/1

The tasks will show up under the task list under Add-Ins and Macros. I had to exclude projects with names "Miscellaneous Files" and "Script Documents" because of an out of memory exception. They're not clickable tasks, so I didn't find it all that useful.

also, on a related note http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/508200/task-comments-in-javascript-are-do-not-show-up-in-task-pane

Comment: Microsoft decommisioned the entire Connect portal rather than fix any bugs that users reported.