# Visual Studio 2012 Task List for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, tasklist

Is it possible to add tasks (Todos, hackes, etc) to  the task list via Comments.
(For **javascript**  files)

Similar to the functions explained here:

- http://code-inside.de/blog-in/2008/11/19/howto-taskmanagement-with-visual-studio-todos-hacks-co/
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l47g7_Qe8HE&feature=player_embedded

The menu points in the second video only apply to Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @JohnSaunders: He's asking whether this can work with comments in Javascript files.

Comment: @SLaks: thanks for the translation

Comment: @SLaks: Yes, I want to add Todos to the task list via Commetns in JavaScript

Comment: Try it :) I tried and it doesn't seem to pick these tags up from .js files.

Comment: Excactly, but in the Video it describes, that it is not enabled for all code files. So maybe one of you knows, if you can enable it, because I don't find the Option... :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The good news is you can get this by installing the extension "JSLint.VS2012".

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1a417c37-4d6f-43ca-b753-6ea6eb5041fd
http://jslint4vs2010.codeplex.com/ (VS2012 version only changes install target)

I found this accidentally as their own documentation (on codeplex) does not reveal they have this. After installing the setting is at Tools | JS Lint Options on the Visual Studio Options tab.

[image: JsLint TODO's demo]

The bad news is it is a bit rough.

1. You end up with multiple instances (with each successive build?). You can manually delete them to start again.
2. Double clicking does not jump to the code. However the File & line columns are there.

Also found via somewhere on SO that Resharper or Telerik JustCode provide this. 
Or an old "Roll your own" solution via [List javascript tasks in Visual Studio Task list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183439/list-javascript-tasks-in-visual-studio-task-list?rq=1) at http://forums.asp.net/t/414634.aspx/1

Comment: Because I have only the express edition, I can't verify this, but I guess this will stay the best answer. Thanks for it.

Answer (score 6):

Another option is the excellent Javascript parser extension:
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/288a2b0f-1357-47b4-8215-1134c36bdf30

I just stumbled on the feature where it supports // TODO: type comments, and you can define your own keywords.

Apparently task list functionality is not available in plain Visual Studio for javascript files.

Comment: This is the best option in my opinion, very easy to use